# renderRequest is not accessible in liferay portlet

Tags: jsp, liferay

Why is the [renderRequest](http://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-2.0-apidocs/javax/portlet/RenderRequest.html) Object accessible in my JSP file?

It is accessible in view.jsp file but in the other jsp files it is not accessible.

I get the error `renderRequest cannot be resolved`

By the way I'm using Eclipse Liferay IDE.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure your jsp has the following taglib included

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />
```

Comment: Also Eclipse may not be compiling the JSP properly, so it's best to try and deploy it and see if there are any compilation errors!

Comment: It depends on what he is trying to do, if he is including the jsp in another jsp(which has this taglib) then he should be able to get renderRequest and at that time Eclipse will definitely complain.

Comment: Agreed! I have just checked and if the first JSP (with the taglib on it) is included on the one where he's trying to access renderRequest then Eclipse will not complain (I've just tried it). So the chances are he hasn't done what you've suggested which is why I voted up your answer! :)

Comment: Note: The reason for this to be required is that there are certain variables defined for generic JSPs (e.g. pageContext). As JSPs get compiled by a JSPcompiler that is not aware of any portal, we'll have to introduce the portal-specific variables - and that's done by <portlet:defineObjects/>. If you want to fully understand this, look at tomcat's compiler's temporary output of java code in the work folder and relate how your jsp is translated to a servlet.

Comment: I get error even when I deploy it. I used request object instead.

Comment: can you please attach the complete jsp content and the stacktrace?

Comment: I'm really sorry. I made a big mistake. I didn't have <portlet:defineObjects/> tag in my jsp file. Thanks all.

Comment: I have `<portlet:defineObjects />` as well as `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>` in `init.jsp` that is being imported in `view.jsp`, The `view.jsp` still complains about renderRequest not being available in eclipse IDE. If I add `<portlet:defineObjects />` to `view.jsp` as well, the error in eclipse goes away. So my question is, Is it okay to put in the `<portlet:defineObjects />` in `view.jsp` even though I have it in `init.jsp`?

Answer (score 1):

if you are adding those TLDs references in `liferay-plugin-package.properties` file, then you can test and if you don't get any compilation error ignore errors like `renderRequest can not be resolved` in IDE , because the IDE might shows error for various objects referenced from portal dependency LTDs like renderRequest etc, when this jsp gets complied at runtime - the TLDs are available from portal and it gets compiled successfully, but make sure to include this taglib in your jsps :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<portlet:defineObjects />
```